# What does '@' do in r?

Tags: r

Why we use `@` in r?

I read some r packages' source code,
for example,
in dplyr-all-equal.R,

```
#' @param target,current Two data frames to compare.
#' @param ignore_col_order Should order of columns be ignored?
#' @param ignore_row_order Should order of rows be ignored?
#' @param convert Should similar classes be converted? Currently this will
```

Why do we need `@` after #? I don't think it has the same use as C language.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. I don't know why I cannot google '@ in r'. The results from google are not relevant...

Comment: You seem to be asking about the `@` symbol in the context of roxygen documentation.  See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html).  The linked 'dupe' is a completely separate use not related to OPs question so have re-opened.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento post the link as an answer or close as "read the manuals"?

Comment: @zx8754 - I was inclined to leave it open, I couldn't find a dupe for it and was hoping someone would provide a more informative response than "read this link".